# A necessary and sufficient condition on a distribution's CDF for there to be a density

Tags: probability-theory

For a distribution to have density, a necessary condition on the distribution's CDF is that it be continuous, but this condition is insufficient. Is there any non-trivial necessary-and-sufficient condition on a distribution's CDF for the distribution to have density?

Comment: Sure: absolute continuity, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions